# Storybook + Vue3 expose methods in `defineExpose` are not visible in argTable automatically

Tags: typescript, vue.js, storybook

i have `CustomInput.vue` like this

```html
<!-- components/input/CustomInput.vue -->

<template>
  <div><!-- some html... --></div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
...

function reset(): void {
  // some reset action...
}

defineExpose({
  reset
})
</script>
```

and i export component like this.

```
// components/input/index.ts

import { default as CustomInput } from './CustomInput.vue'

type CustomInput = InstanceType<typeof CustomInput>

export { CustomInput }
```

so i can show `reset` method type is `() => void` in `CustonInput` ref.

```html
...

<script setup lang="ts">
...

const inputRef = ref<CustomInput>()

const fn = () => {
  inputRef.value?.reset()
}
</script>
```

but in storybook i can't see any expose method.

Do I have to write expose method in argTable separately?

this is my storybook stories code.

```
import type { Meta, StoryObj } from '@storybook/vue3'

import { CustomInput } from '../components/input'

const meta = {
  title: 'Components/CustomInput',
  component: CustomInput,
  tags: ['autodocs'],
} satisfies Meta<CustomInput>

export default meta
type Story = StoryObj<typeof meta>
```

I know there is a way to manually write in argTable, but I wish it would be created automatically.